# In there any way to mark code to prevent it from being committed to SVN or Git?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I find myself adding Debugging code that I am worried it will be mistakenly committed to the repository. I usually mark this with a "Don't commit this" warning. but then I have to comment/delete this code before committing and then add it again to the project.

Is there any way to mark a piece of code so it will be ignored by SVN or Git?
Just like git_ignore but for code inside a file.

Comment: You could write a hook for git... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840196/aborting-git-pre-commit-hook-when-var-dump-present  ... Not sure about SVN.

Comment: I think it's better to create a setting and enable/disable that part of code.

Comment: For git, do your development on a temporary branch and commit anything you like. Clean up any debugging code before committing the code to a permanent branch or pushing to an upstream repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, there is a special built-in changelist called "ignore-on-commit" designed exactly for this situation. Any file you put on this changelist will by default be unselected when you open the commit dialog. If you want you can still select it manually however in case you accidentally leave a file there.

Answer (score 0):

In Subversion, you can create [change lists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html).

You can put the code you don't want to change in one change list, and then the code you want to change in another change list. Then, you can commit the changes in one change list, and then revert the other.

Comment: @shannoga's comment: "Just like git_ignore but *for code inside a file*" so changelists won't do,.